# Return from java to JNI by reference

Tags: java, c++, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I need to pass an array and an integer out from a java method which is called by JNI.

```
public static int foo(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] buffer;
    // Fill buffer with data
    data = buffer;  // <--- This doesn't work as the pointer is changed
    return bufferSize;
}
```

At the line indicated it is my understanding that the pointer is changed but the reference I have in JNI to `data` which I passed in doesn't update so I don't get the new data.

How would I go about returning extra data though parameters?

Comment: You'll need to pass objects, and use their setters to modify their values.

Comment: Ok, how would that work if I wanted to return an integer by parameter given the `Integer` is immutable?

Comment: You would have to take a wrapper as a parameter that contains a reference to an `Integer`, and allocate such new `Integer`. It would be better if you could refactor your code to not do it.

Comment: Return the integer value, and wrap the native pointer in a direct ByteBuffer (which Java can manipulate).

Comment: If the byte array were to be wrapped in a ByteBuffer would it be possible to resize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to K-ballo:

The byte array needed to be in a wrapper class.

```
class ByteArrayWrapper {
    public ByteArrayWrapper() {}
    public byte[] array;
}
```

In JNI I create an instance of this class and pass it to the method.

```
public static int foo(ByteArrayWrapper data) {
    byte[] buffer;
    // Fill buffer with data
    data.array = buffer;
    return bufferSize;
}
```

The instance of `ByteArrayWrapper` in JNI now contains the new byte array which can be accessed by using the `jfieldID` for that property.